# Error installing certbot on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, certbot

Following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt) to install Certbot on an Amazon Linux 2 server.

At the step of installing Certbot like this:

`sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache`

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Package: 1:mod_ssl-2.4.46-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
           Requires: httpd = 2.4.46-2.amzn2
           Installed: httpd-2.4.48-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.48-1.amzn2
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.amzn2.6.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.6-67.amzn2.6.1
           Available: httpd-2.4.33-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.33-2.amzn2.0.2
           Available: httpd-2.4.33-2.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.33-2.amzn2.0.3
           Available: httpd-2.4.33-2.amzn2.1.0.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.33-2.amzn2.1.0
           Available: httpd-2.4.34-1.amzn2.1.0.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.34-1.amzn2.1.0
           Available: httpd-2.4.34-1.amzn2.1.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.34-1.amzn2.1.1
           Available: httpd-2.4.37-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.37-1.amzn2.0.1
           Available: httpd-2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1
           Available: httpd-2.4.41-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.41-1.amzn2.0.1
           Available: httpd-2.4.43-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.43-1.amzn2
           Available: httpd-2.4.46-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.46-1.amzn2
           Available: httpd-2.4.46-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               httpd = 2.4.46-2.amzn2
```

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the same date as you, and so kept an eye on this question for answers. Today I found that running through the commands again no longer produces the issue for me.